# How to set Summernote text from ASP.Net Webforms codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, summernote

I have included Summernote into an ASP.NET Webforms page, but when I try to set the text for it from codebehind the html text appears but the toolbar disappears.

This is what Summernote looks like before setting the text...[default Summernote look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYplE.jpg)

This is how it looks when a try to set the text...[setting the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v4zw.jpg)

This is my includes for Summernote and Bootstrap...

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
```

My Summernote html and javascript is...

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Body" class="myLargeFont"></asp:Label>
    <textarea ClientIdMode="Static" id="summernote" name="summernote" runat="server" style="width:650px; height:550px;"></textarea>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstAttachments" runat="server" Visible="false" Height="200px" Width="150px"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowAttachment" runat="server" Text="Load" Visible="false" />
</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Hello Bootstrap 4',
            //tabsize: 2,
            height: 300,
            toolbar: [
                // [groupName, [list of button]]
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['height', ['height']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                ['view', ['codeview']]
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code for the button to set the text is...

```
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddEmail" runat="server" Text="Add email" class="myLargeFont" OnClick="btnAddEmail_Click" />
</p>

private static string summernoteTextTest()
{
    string testText = "<p>This is some text for testing in summernote.</p><p>How does it look?</p>";
    return testText;
}

protected void btnAddEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string testtext = summernoteTextTest();
    summernote.InnerText = testtext;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help, please?